# 'Listening' for a file in Python

Tags: python

I have a python script that does some updates on my database.

The files that this script needs are saved in a directory at around 3AM by some other process.

So I'm going to schedule a cron job to run daily at 3AM; but I want to handle the case if the file is not available exactly at 3AM, it could be delayed by some interval.

So I basically need to keep checking whether the file of some particular name exists every 5 minutes starting from 3AM. I'll try for around 1 hour, and give up if it doesn't work out.

How can I achieve this sort of thing in Python?

Comment: Does 'listdir' help? http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/os_listdir.htm

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try something like this (you'll need to change the print statements to be function calls if you are using Python 3).

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import os
import time

def watch_file( filename, time_limit=3600, check_interval=60 ):
    '''Return true if filename exists, if not keep checking once every check_interval seconds for time_limit seconds.
    time_limit defaults to 1 hour
    check_interval defaults to 1 minute
    '''

    now = time.time()
    last_time = now + time_limit

    while time.time() <= last_time:
        if os.path.exists( filename ):
             return True
        else:
            # Wait for check interval seconds, then check again.
            time.sleep( check_interval )

    return False

if __name__ == '__main__':
    filename = '/the/file/Im/waiting/for.txt'
    time_limit = 3600 # one hour from now.
    check_interval = 60 # seconds between checking for the file.

    if watch_file( filename, time_limit, check_interval ):
        print "File present!"
    else:
        print "File not found after waiting:", time_limit, " seconds!"
```

Comment: This is a fine approach in general.  `file_processed` is not necessary as you don't use it, and `return False` is also not-needed, but I guess `explicit is better than implicit`.

Answer (score 6):

For this sort of task, you need to use [`watchdog`](http://pythonhosted.org/watchdog/) a library for listening to and monitoring system events.

One of the events it can monitor is file system events, via the [`FileSystemEventHandler`](http://pythonhosted.org/watchdog/api.html#watchdog.events.FileSystemEventHandler) class, which has `on_created()` method.

You'll end up writing a "wrapper" script, it can be running continuously. This script will use watchdog to listen on that particular directory.  The moment a file is created, this script will be notified - you'll have to then check if the file created matches the pattern of the target file, and then execute your custom code.

Luckily, as this is a common task - there is a `PatternMatchingEventHandler` already available, which inherits from `FileSystemEventHandler` but watches for files matching a pattern.

Your wrapper script then becomes:

```
from watchdog.observers import Observer  
from watchdog.events import PatternMatchingEventHandler

class FileWatcher(PatternMatchingEventHandler):
    patterns = ["*.dat"] # adjust as required

    def process(self, event):
       # your actual code goes here

       # event.src_path will be the full file path
       # event.event_type will be 'created', 'moved', etc.
       print('{} observed on {}'.format(event.event_type, event.src_path))

    def on_created(self, event):
       self.process(event)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    obs = Observer() # This is what manages running of your code
    obs.schedule(FileWatcher(), path='/the/target/dir')
    obs.start() # Start watching

    try:
        while True:
            time.sleep(1)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        ob.stop()

    obs.join()
```

Comment: OP asked for a check in interval of every 5 minutes irrespective of file change before this time. Does watchdog has this ? I think watchdog monitors directoy all the time instead in intervals. Isnt it ?

Answer (score -1):

That is what comes to my mind first, pretty straight forward:

```
from time import sleep
counter = 0
working = True
while counter < 11 and working:
    try:
        # Open file and do whatever you need
        working = False
    except IOError:
        counter +=1
        sleep(5*60)
```

***Better solution***

```
from time import sleep
counter = 0
working = True
while counter < 11 and working:
    if os.path.isfile('path/to/your/file')
        # Open file and do whatever you need
        working = False
    else:
        counter +=1
        sleep(5*60)
```

Answer (score -1):

In Python you can check if the file exists

```
import os.path
os.path.isfile(filename)
```

Then you set your cron to run every 5 minutes from 3am:
*/5 3 * * * /path-to-your/script.py

You can write in a simple file to control wether you already read the data from file or not (or a database if you are already using one)

Answer (score -1):

You can use Twisted, and it is reactor it is much better than an infinite loop ! Also you can use reactor.callLater(myTime, myFunction), and when myFunction get called you can adjust the myTime and add another callback with the same API callLater().

Comment: Twisted is an awesome framework... I have used it extensively over the past 10 years.  But if it is a hammer, this problem is not a nail.  Using Twisted for this is the definition of overkill unless you are already using and are familiar with it.

Comment: I do agree it is overkill, but still a solution and a valid one, and i don't like putting code inside infinite loops soo ...

Comment: It's not an infinite loop.  The upvoted answer has a definite end time.  I don't know the intricacies of how callLater does its thing, but I would guess the reactor does multiple checks to see if it is time to run now (which might be a tight loop if there is nothing else for the reactor to do.)

Comment: 10 years of Twisted you say ! you should read about the reactor then and its different engine behind it !

Comment: Indeed, it appears all of the eventing backends support a scheduled event, so indeed, it does not create any tight loop.  It is still overkill.